# Xamarin HtmlWebViewSource not Binding

Tags: xaml, xamarin, binding

This binding does show me my html:

```
<Label Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding theInstructions}" />
```

so I think I have the binding right.

And this WebView does display Google:

```
<WebView Grid.Row="1" Source="http://www.google.com" />
```

so WebView itself is working in my ContentPage.

But this WebView with binding doesn't display a thing regardless of how simple I make the html:

```
<WebView 
    Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
    <WebView.Source>
        <HtmlWebViewSource Html="{Binding theInstructions}" />
    </WebView.Source>
</WebView>
```

What am I missing here?

EDIT EDIT EDIT

Leo is basically right here so kudos. It's not a binding problem it's a layout problem.

The following code does display HTML:

```
<WebView Grid.Row="1">
        <WebView.Source>
            <HtmlWebViewSource Html="{Binding theInstructions}" />
        </WebView.Source>
    </WebView>
```

But ONLY if the HTML is short enough. Make it one line longer and it disappears.

And I've tried dozens of combinations of StackLayouts, ScrollView, HeightRequests, MinHeightRequests and so on. Anything else I do makes the HTML go away - even the short stuff much less the long stuff.

I'm stunned Xamarin is still this bad after this long...

So ... this is still an open question. Apparently bound web views have an issue???

Comment: Could it work ?

Answer (score 0):

It may be necessary to set the `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest` properties of the **WebView** to see the HTML content, depending upon the layout the WebView is a child of. For example, this is required in a **StackLayout**.

So try to change like:

```
<StackLayout>
   <WebView WidthRequest="1000" HeightRequest="1000">
       <WebView.Source>
           <HtmlWebViewSource Html="{Binding theInstructions}" />
       </WebView.Source>
   </WebView>
</StackLayout>
```